# Remove JSON keys that have an array of object with their values undefined

Tags: javascript, json

i have an JSON like this and i want to remove all the keys that have an array of objects with their values undefined.

```
{
  '2020-07-27': [{ 
    name: "Study",
    time: "11:30 - 12:30",
    week: "monday"
  }],
  '2020-08-01': [{ 
    name: "undefined",
    time: "undefined",
    week: "undefined"
  }],
  '2020-08-03': [{ 
    name: "Study",
    time: "11:30 - 12:30",
    week: "monday"
  }],
  '2020-08-07': [{ 
    name: "undefined",
    time: "undefined",
    week: "undefined"
  }],
}
```

This is what I want to do

```
{
  '2020-07-27': [{ 
    name: "Study",
    time: "11:30 - 12:30",
    week: "monday"
  }],
  '2020-08-03': [{ 
    name: "Study",
    time: "11:30 - 12:30",
    week: "monday"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the json and check for each of the key value pair and delete if value is undefined.

```js
  var json= {
              '2020-07-27': [{ 
              name: "Study",
              time: "11:30 - 12:30",
              week: "monday"
            }],
              '2020-08-01': [{ 
              name: "undefined",
              time: "undefined",
              week: "undefined"
            }],
              '2020-08-03': [{ 
              name: "Study",
              time: "11:30 - 12:30",
              week: "monday"
            }],
              '2020-08-07': [{ 
              name: "undefined",
              time: "undefined",
              week: "undefined"
            }],
 }
 
 for (var i in json) {
 obj=json[i][0]
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] == "undefined" ? delete json[i] : {});
 }
 
  console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try these following step:

- use `Object.entries()` to transform object to list of key-value pairs (in this case is date and array of one object)
- iterate through that key-value pairs array, filter and ignore pairs that have the array containing your unwanted object
- use `Object.fromEntries()` to transform the key-value pairs back to object

```js
const x = {
  "2020-07-27": [
    {
      name: "Study",
      time: "11:30 - 12:30",
      week: "monday",
    },
  ],
  "2020-08-01": [
    {
      name: "undefined",
      time: "undefined",
      week: "undefined",
    },
  ],
  "2020-08-03": [
    {
      name: "Study",
      time: "11:30 - 12:30",
      week: "monday",
    },
  ],
  "2020-08-07": [
    {
      name: "undefined",
      time: "undefined",
      week: "undefined",
    },
  ],
}

const res = Object.entries(x).filter(
  ([date, array]) =>
    !Object.values(array[0]).every((value) => value === "undefined")
)

console.log(Object.fromEntries(res))
```